# How to show different sub sites based on Member's user name in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a website for a company with lots of sub sites using multisites in WordPress. These sub sites are password protected and those are for different clients.

Lets say for an example

- my main site is `www.example.com`
- and I have two sub sites called `www.example.com/client_one` and `www.example.com/client_two`.

I want to have the client login window in my main site `www.example.com`, with username and password.

What I want to do is, if a member from client one enters his or her given username and password correctly, then I want to redirect them in to `www.example.com/client_one` page.

Same way for other member from client two:  `www.example.com/client_two`

Is it possible to do in WordPress ? Do I need any plugins to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer under following link .

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatic-redirection-to-child-site-from-main?replies=15#post-1844523